# How to access postgreSQL database using Mule pattern?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, mule

Im able to log some message but how to change it to access a database and send those messages and store there?

i know the database part is disconected from the pattern but tried somethings and nothing worked so far..

code:

```
<scripting:transformer name="noopLoggingTransformer">
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        log.info "insert into inbound_messages (payload, timestamp, agent, ip_from, endpoint, soap_operation) values ('',now(), ${message.getInboundProperty('user-agent')}, ${message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS')}, ${message.getInboundProperty('http.request')}, '');"
        message
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>

<pattern:web-service-proxy name="service" transformer-refs="noopLoggingTransformer" inboundAddress="${serverName}/services/Logradouros/LogradouroServico" outboundAddress="${targetServer}/servicos/v2/LogradouroServico.svc" wsdlFile="LogradouroServicos.wsdl">
</pattern:web-service-proxy>

<jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source name="dbconection" user="${database.user}" password="${database.pass}" url="${database.url}" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source">
</jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source>

<jdbc-ee:connector name="jdbcConnector" dataSource-ref="dbconection" validateConnections="false" transactionPerMessage="true" queryTimeout="10" pollingFrequency="10000" doc:name="JDBC"> 
    <jdbc-ee:query key="querymsg" value="insert into inbound_messages (payload, timestamp, agent, ip_from, endpoint, soap_operation) values ('', now(), '','','')"></jdbc-ee:query>  
</jdbc-ee:connector>
```

What i did after was try a different aproach:

```
<flow name="logradouros-autenticacao" doc:name="logradouros-autenticacao"> 
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="${webservice.logradouros.in.autenticacao.path}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="HTTP"></servlet:inbound-endpoint>  
    <async doc:name="Async"> 
        <flow-ref name="log-request" doc:name="Flow Reference"></flow-ref>  
    </async>  
    <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${webservice.logradouros.out.protocol}://${webservice.logradouros.out.host}/${webservice.logradouros.out.autenticacao.path}" doc:name="Generic"></outbound-endpoint>  
</flow>

<flow name="log-request" doc:name="log-request"> 
    <logger message="1-&gt; #[groovy:payload.getClass()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="insertMsg" responseTimeout="10000" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Persist raw message"></jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>  
    <logger message="#[header:INBOUND:Host] #[header:INBOUND:http.method] #[message.inboundProperties.entrySet().toString()] #[groovy:payload.toString()] #[groovy: return message.getInboundPropertyNames().toString()] #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('request.parameters').toString()]" level="INFO" category="mule.http.accesslog" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
    <logger message="#[message.outboundProperties.entrySet().toString()]" level="INFO" category="mule.http.accesslog" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
</flow>
```

its not 100% but it may workout, the approach through pattern wasnt working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your transformer, use `muleContext.client` to dispatch messages to VM queue consumed by another flow, which will take care of insert data in the DB.

So in your case, something similar to the following should work:

```
<scripting:transformer name="noopLoggingTransformer">
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.client.dispatch('vm://log-request.in', message)
        message
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>

<pattern:web-service-proxy name="service" transformer-refs="noopLoggingTransformer" inboundAddress="${serverName}/services/Logradouros/LogradouroServico" outboundAddress="${targetServer}/servicos/v2/LogradouroServico.svc" wsdlFile="LogradouroServicos.wsdl" />

<flow name="log-request" doc:name="log-request"> 
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="log-request.in" />
    <logger message="1-&gt; #[groovy:payload.getClass()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="insertMsg" responseTimeout="10000" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Persist raw message" />
    <!-- TODO use MEL, not these old style expressions -->
    <logger message="#[header:INBOUND:Host] #[header:INBOUND:http.method] #[message.inboundProperties.entrySet().toString()] #[groovy:payload.toString()] #[groovy: return message.getInboundPropertyNames().toString()] #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('request.parameters').toString()]" level="INFO" category="mule.http.accesslog" doc:name="Logger" />  
    <logger message="#[message.outboundProperties.entrySet().toString()]" level="INFO" category="mule.http.accesslog" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Ok, searching the web about examples or documentation i found none, any docs or example on that matter?

Comment: Not sure what blocks you here or what example you're looking for? Have you tried anything? Did you read http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/client/MuleClient.html ?

Comment: i did read that but wanst clear on how would i change my transformer or pattern to log messages over postgreSQL... and was searching for more answers on that matter, placing a search over internet wasnt able to find someone or some example/documentation using muleContext.client or something like that...

Comment: Using the MuleClient is covered extensively in chapter 12 of Mule in Action, second edition. But it's one line of Groovy code we're talking about here so really it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Since i have the book i will take a look on that chapter and se what can i do

Comment: OK, since you're question is about pattern, I'm answering for the pattern.